# Having trouble with return values of strcmp(). How exactly does strcmp() work?

Tags: c, string, ctype

I'm having an issue with solving a coding exercise and during debugging I've noticed that my `strcmp()` function doesn't work as I expected. The `strcmp()` function returns the wrong value compared to what I would expect. Perhaps I'm lacking some crucial undertanding of how `strcmp()` really works.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
     char string[] = "dogs";
     char compare[] = "bark";

     int result = strcmp(string, compare);

     printf("int result = %d\n", result);
}
```

The return value of the program is:
`int result = 2`
which is unexpected for me since the documentation of `strcmp()` states that:

`strcmp(string_A, string_B)`

- `string_A` > `string_B` ==> return value >0
- `string_A` < `string_B` ==> return value <0
- `string_A` == `string_B` ==> return value =0

In my example `strcmp(string, compare)` or `strcmp("dogs", "bark")` the return value should be less than 0 since `"dogs"` < `"bark"` but it keeps returning 2 which I'm also not sure if it's expected behaviour that it always prints out the same integer.

Comment: Why do you say "dogs" < "bark"? Isn't it the case that 'd' > 'b'?

Comment: "dog(s)" comes **after** "bark" in my dictionary... Seriously, 'd' is 2 characters higher in the ASCII table than 'b'. This is why the return value is 2, and not some other random value greater than 0.

Comment: man... so from what I understand now it compares the ASCII values and in ASCII 'd' has a greater value than 'b'. If that's the actual solution I feel quite stupid for that. For some reason I thought the alphabetical order would mean 'a' is the greatest value.

Comment: Search "ascii table" on google images... There's an abundance of tables you can study...

Comment: @odan797 First God created the dog and only then did it start barking..:)

Comment: @odan797 it seems you thought that 0 is greater than 2 because natural numbers start from 0.:)

Comment: Ye idk I just had an absolute wrong understanding of what greater than means in terms of the alphabet. I apologize though that one was way too obvious and thank you all for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the return value should be less than 0 since "dogs" < "bark"

False.

Since 'd' comes after 'b', or more specifically since the character code for 'd' is greater than the character code for 'b', the former is considered greater, and therefore a value greater than 0 is returned.

Comment: To address the last sentence of the question: Portable code should not pay attention to any detail of the value returned by `strcmp` beyond whether it is positive, negative, or zero. However, an implementation that didn't always return the same actual number if called many times on the same pair of input strings would be very unusual. `'d' - 'b' == 2` and so I suspect your implementation of `strcmp` happens to return the numeric value of the difference between the first pair of characters that aren't the same, but that's not something you should ever rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about alphabets and social constructs/conventions. Programmers/computers think differently than common folk. In general we just enumerate things from 0 and upwards.

Or in case of letters, computers use a symbol table code:

- `'b'` == 98
- `'d'` == 100
- 98 < 100

For the same reason `"Dog"` is less than `"dog"`, because `'D'` == 68.

Comment: Similarly, in the Swedish alphabet we have 29 letters, it ends with `...ZÅÄÖ`. So a naive Swedish programmer might think that `strcmp("Å","Ä")` should result in < 0 since thats how the alphabet goes. But the symbol table codes for these is often something like 197 and 196, so the assumption is wrong.